# String length difference in VB.net 3.5 and 4

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, character-encoding

I have just updated an in-house app from .Net 3.5 to 4. and I'm having some issues with string encoding. I have a string I am adding to the registry. It is encrypted (as a byte array), then converted to a string using encoding windows-1252.

When I pull it out of the registry, I test the length. Using VB.net 3.5 `.Length` gives me 23. Using .Net 4 I get 35. The .Net 4 version is longer but it just has extra null characters at the end. This has flow on repercussions with how the decryption process works. Did something change in default text encoding or something?

.Net4 is below. The .Net 3.5 version comes out the same but with no padding of 0s

```
(0): 13
(1): 49
(2): 27
(3): 42
(4): 102
(5): 77
(6): 178
(7): 197
(8): 98
(9): 198
(10): 240
(11): 79
(12): 171
(13): 216
(14): 82
(15): 55
(16): 24
(17): 134
(18): 117
(19): 97
(20): 223
(21): 69
(22): 149
(23): 0
(24): 0
(25): 0
(26): 0
(27): 0
(28): 0
(29): 0
(30): 0
(31): 0
(32): 0
(33): 0
```

EDIT:

So the input into the registry has the padding. It just appears that getting it from the registry results in different string.

I'm using this to get it from the Reg:

```
Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(//Location, False)
val = poKey.GetValue(name)
```

So my simplest solution will be to get rid of the padding when I add the string, but any  thoughts as to why it's different?

Comment: what code are you using to encode the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a byte[] that contains random binary data to a string with the Encoding class is fundamentally wrong, it is a lossy conversion.  Possibly exacerbated by then having the registry trying to interpret an 8-bit encoded string as a valid utf-16 string.  The outcome will be quite unpredictable.

You *must* use an encoding that's capable of handling arbitrary binary data.  Like Convert.ToBase64String().

Or, more productively, by storing it as binary data in the registry instead of a string so no conversion is required at all.  Note the RegistryKey.SetValue() overload that takes a [RegistryValueKind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind.aspx),  you are interested in the RegistryValueKind.Binary option.  Not actually necessary to use that overload, just pass the byte[] directly and do not attempt any conversion at all.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. Just strange that the behaviour is different.